# jQuery remove object from object collection

Tags: jquery, object

I have the following example code, creating a object collection.

How can I remove one of the objects? (e.g. $TestList would look as though the "delete me" item was never there.
I've tried .remove, .splice, .delete etc but I'm told it's not a function.

Doing typeof($TestList) brings back object, and typeof($TestList[0]) also seems valid.

Surely I don't have to recreate the collection without one item?

```
(function($) { 

jQuery.QuickTest = {
    $TestList: {},
    build: function()
    {
        $TestList={};
        $TestList[0] = 
        {
            title: "part 1"
        };

        $TestList[1] = 
        {
            title: "delete me please"
        };

        $TestList[2] = 
        {
            title: "part 2"
        };

    }
}

jQuery.fn.QuickTest = jQuery.QuickTest.build;   

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {

$().QuickTest(
{
})
});
```

We're using jQuery 1.3.

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't `$()` only start working since 1.4? Besides that, could you share with us what this piece of code is supposed to do?

Comment: Btw, `$TestList` is implied global, which is a bad idea.

Comment: @Jack: Before 1.4, `$()` would return a jQuery object containing the `document` element.

Comment: @Matt Ah ... well, that makes this code even harder to understand ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Review**

First of all, it's very non-obvious what your code is supposed to do, but here are some issues:

```
jQuery.QuickTest = {
    $TestList: {},
    build: function()
    {
        $TestList={};
```

You define `jQuery.QuickTest.$TestList`, but inside `build()` you declare a *global* object `$TestList`.

Functions declared under `jQuery.fn` are supposed to act on a matched set of elements (referenced by `this`) and return it as well; your function does neither.

**Answers**

An answer to some of your questions:

1. `.remove()` is a jQuery function that removes nodes from the DOM and needs to be called on a jQuery object.
2. `.splice()` only applies to `Array` and even though you're accessing `$TestList` as if it were one, it's still just an `Object`.
3. `.delete()` is not any function I know ;-)

**Possible solution**

To delete an entry from `$TestList` you could use the `delete` in this fashion:

```
delete $TestList[1];
```

Comment: Excellent thanks very much!

It is a completely cut down version of my code with only the absolute basics so yes, it is a bit open so sorry about that.

But your explanation has given me lots to look at, so thanks very much! Quite difficult these days finding what you are trying to do when you don't really know the words to use. It was my way of doing an object available to all my other functions without having to pass it everywhere.

and delete is exactly what I needed. :-)

Answer (score 7):

use `delete myObject`, not `myObject.delete`

Comment: By the way this is just javascript and will work without jQuery

Comment: Will not remove the object completely. Instead, it will leave it as  `null`.